# Java import error while compiling

Tags: java, gradle, akka, importerror

I'm working on an project with AKKA. It's a Gradle project, and when I run it within IDE Eclipse it works. Then I tried to compile it from terminal with `javac -d bin/ src/a.java` command, but it does not compile due to this error:

```
java:3: error: package akka.actor does not exist
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
```

This is the project folder structure: *project > src,bin* and then *src > a.java, b.java*. 
Both *a.java* and *b.java* contain some imports for AKKA like:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if it's a gradle project, you should compile it with gradle, not javac... javac has no way to know what dependencies you need and where they are.

Comment: That's not how you should compile your gradle project. Try using gradle command to build. And it's not possible which command to use without seeing the build file.

Comment: Or you *can* compile the code with javac, but you'll need to put all the relevant jar files on the classpath. (I'm not recommending that you do so, but I just want to emphasize that Gradle doesn't change the nature of the Java code you write, or the fact that is *is* compiled with javac or something similar. It's just managing the dependencies for you.)

Comment: @assylias Running from terminal with `gradle run` works. I didn't know that those imports may be a problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, maybe it's not something on which I want to spend much more time, I cannot manage the dependencies by myself. I was trying to avoid IDE, but I didn't have the knowledge to manage this in a Gradle project.

Comment: Yes, you need to use build tool as much as possible, such as `maven, sbt, gradle`. If you want to use javac, you had to use `javac -cp **.jar`, this is really terrible.

Comment: @lagom Ok, and why are there no problems with all java.* imports? I suppose they are available in the local jvm, while akka's ones need to be imported from the outside, am I right?

Comment: Yes, JVM use 3 kinds class loader to load class: `Bootstrploader` for `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib,-Xbootclasspath, %JAVA_HOME%/jre/classes`, `ExtClassLoader ` for `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext`, and finally `AppClassLoader ` for user library, `akka library` just the third not included in JVM.

Comment: @lagom So, theoretically I should download and save the required AKKA libraries, or any external lib, and tell java compiler to load them from that local folder. The paths you mentioned contain the java libs?

Comment: @Caramelleamare Yes, you are true. But this is just theoretically, `maven, sbt, gradle` already do that for us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166586/discussion-between-caramelleamare-and-lagom).